# el print despues de while no me funciona

Tags: python

```
print("Bienvenido")

contraseña = "eureka"

correcto = True

contador = 0

while contador >= 3 and correcto == False :

    print("Ingrese la contraseña")
    contraseña = input()

    if contraseña == "eureka" :
        print("Contraseña correcta")
        correcto = True

    else :
        print("Contraseña incorrecta")
        contador += 1

        if contador >= 3 :
            print("no tiene mas intentos")
```

Comment: si contador empieza siendo cero, el bucle no se ejecutará ni siquiera una vez. ademas de que la otra condición (correcto==False) tampoco se cumple.

Comment: El while se ejecuta siempre y cuando se cumpla la condición, tu condición es que contador sea igual o mayor de 3 y contador vale zero, por lo que no entra en el while. La condición de correcto también impide que se ejecute el while.

Comment: me podria exlicar mas o menos como seria

Comment: Es más elegante, claro y conciso usa `not correcto` en lugar de `correcto == False`

Comment: Hola nosoy, bienvenido, como te indica abulafia, hay un error en la condición de tu ***while***, debería ser: ***contador <= 3 and correcto***, y luego en el **if** pones: ***correcto = False***. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: al acomodarlo como me dice Marce Puente funciona pero queda infinito y necesito que termine al tener 3 intentos incorrectos

Comment: sigue infinito enserio me podrian ayudar corrigiendolo

Answer (score 1):

Con pocas correcciones, sacamos adelante tu código:

```
contraseña = "eureka"
contador = 0
while contador < 3:
    print("Ingrese la contraseña")
    contraseña = input()
    if contraseña == "eureka" :
        print("Contraseña correcta")
        break
    else :
        print( f" Contraseña incorrecta {contador}" )
        contador += 1
        if contador == 3 :
            print("no tiene mas intentos")

print( "salimos" )
```

Como ves, quité **correcto** porque me pareció innecesario (puedes agregarlo si te place), cambié la condición del **while**, y agregue un **break** para salir cuando la contraseña es correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Agregando al ejemplo de Marce Puente, si le pones un contador al if en 1, te va a devolver en que intento se acertó.

```html
contraseña = "eureka"
contador = 0
while contador < 3:
    print("Ingrese la contraseña")
    contraseña = input()
    if contraseña == "eureka" :
        contador += 1
        print(f"Contraseña correcta. acertada en el intento {contador}")
        break
    else :
        print( f" Contraseña incorrecta {contador}" )
        contador += 1
        if contador == 3 :
            print("no tiene mas intentos")

print( "salimos" )
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, muy buena tu idea, aunque no está bien implementada, siempre mostrara "**acertada en el intento 1**", lo que no necesariamente es correcto, entiendo que lo que querías hacer, era sumarle uno a contador (lo haces después del print), osea deberías ***cambiar contador = 1*** por ***contador += 1***, y quitar el segundo.

Comment: Sii Marce tal cual eso es lo que pretendía. 
Gracias por la corrección, no había notado el error!

Answer (score 0):

¿Es necesario usar la variable correcto?. La reemplacé por intentos así podes avisarle al usuario cuántos le quedan:

```
print("Bienvenido")

contraseña = "eureka"
intentos = 3
contador = 0


while contador < 3:
    print("Ingrese su contraseña")
    contraseña = input()
    if contraseña == "eureka":
        print("Contraseña correcta")
        break
    else:
        intentos-=1
        print(f"Contraseña incorrecta. Quedan {intentos} intentos")
        contador+=1
        if contador == 3:
            print("No tiene mas intentos")
```